# uninitialized constant Rack::ContentLength (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
amol@chikhaldara:~/exp/blog$ rails s
Exiting
/home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/async-rack-0.5.1/lib/async_rack/async_callback.rb:7:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Rack::ContentLength (NameError)
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/async-rack-0.5.1/lib/async_rack/async_callback.rb:7:in `AsyncCallback'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/async-rack-0.5.1/lib/async_rack/content_length.rb:4:in `<module:AsyncRack>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/async-rack-0.5.1/lib/async_rack/content_length.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:6:in `<module:Rack>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:43:in `rescue in default'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:40:in `default'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/amol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
amol@chikhaldara:~/exp/blog$
```

just got stuck with this, any hints how to resolve this

Comment: plz give me some time to reproduce this, It was when I played with rails328 and omniauth, no device